# Why is $x$ restricted this way? (limits of functions)

Tags: limits, functions, intuition

Here is a corollary from Ross' Elementary Analysis:
[image]

Why is $x$ restricted this way?

Comment: "$x\rightarrow a^+$" means $x$ is approaching $a$ from the right (so, with $x>a$).

Comment: Okay, that explains the $a+\delta$ part, why must $x$ be greater than $0$?

Comment: I think it should be $a<x<a+\delta$.

Comment: @OscarFlores I think is a typo of text

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Comment: Yeah, if it was $a$, that'd make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Is a typo of the text; in other edition say:

[image]